# What is the P in 'nope' called?

Tags: single-word-requests, etymology, phonology

**Nope** is another form of *No*. When we say this other form, we say **p** in it. What is this p called? Where did it come from?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

### Brief answer:

*Nope* is a variant of ***no*** (exclamation), usually pronounced as [nəʊp̚] (AmE [noʊp̚].

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nope#h1) says its first known use dates back to 1888; however, according to [Wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nope), it was used for the first time in the 1850s.

The P in *nope* is **epenthetic** and the process of adding it is called **[Epenthesis](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/552719/365490)**.

### Explanation:

**Epenthesis** is the pronunciation of an unhistorical sound within a word usually added for articulatory reasons. Consonants and vowels are usually inserted into words for the sake of ease. Epenthesis happens for a variety of reasons, some of them are:

- to prevent adjacent vowels in a hiatus, for instance, *idea of* is pronounced *idearof*, with an epenthetic *r*, in most non-rhotic accents to avoid a hiatus
- another reason is to simplify consonant clusters, for instance, most Indian English speakers pronounce 'school' ***i**school* (breaking the cluster /sk/)
- between a nasal and a fricative (*prince-prints* merger)

Some sources call it 'excrescence', though the technical and widely used term for this is **epenthesis**.

Regarding *nope*, the P represents the closing of lips after saying *No.* (exclamation).

Suppose someone asked you a question and you said "No". You would usually pause after saying "No" (exclamation) with your lips already positioned to produce a P.

Other examples include *yep*, *yup* and *welp* ('well'). *Yep* and *yup* are the variants of 'yeah' ('yes') as an isolated or emphatic utterance (exclamation), with P representing closing of the lips, creating an **[unreleased](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_audible_release) bilabial stop [[p̚]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_bilabial_stop)**.

Spanish does the same with *si* (meaning: yes). *Si* → *sip*.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109301/discussion-on-answer-by-decapitated-soul-what-is-the-p-in-nope-called).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Auto-correct (annoying but extremely useful at times)

Comment: I'll take that as a compliment.

Answer (score 8):

There are two other words that are similar to *nope*:

- Yup
- Welp

[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/welp) has the etymologies and the term for this (unreleased labial stop):

> ORIGIN OF WELP
>
> First recorded in 1945–50; form of *well* as an isolated or emphatic utterance, with an excrescent *p* representing closing of the lips, creating an unreleased labial stop; compare the parallel use of *p* in [nope](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/nope) and [yup](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/yup).

Comment: https://youtu.be/ir1sVy9JLyo?t=60

Comment: You have copied the explanation of welp and the question is about nope. Dumb point but still I hope it makes sense