# "a" and "an" - What is the name for adding characters for better pronunciation?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, linguistics

We say "a while" but "an hour". The **n** seems to be added for better pronunciation.
What is the name for this linguistic construct (adding characters to improve pronunciation)?

In French, latent word-final consonants are pronounced before a vowel sound which is known as "Liaison" but this seems to be the wrong term for the addition of characters in English.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the P in 'nope' called?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/535948/what-is-the-p-in-nope-called) /// It's called **epenthetic**.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul But the question is mistaken: letters were removed from the Old English word "an" (one) to get "a", not the reverse.

Comment: I know about the history of *a/an*, but I don't think that's what the OP is asking about. If I understand it correctly, the OP wants a word for the addition of sounds for better pronunciation, for example, why we use *an* in front of a word beginning with a vowel and *a* before a consonant. And that's epenthesis which is covered in the linked answer.