# Deciphering two words from their Archaic spellings

Tags: etymology, archaicisms, early-modern-english, middle-english, research

I am translating the 1509, first English Translation of [Sebastian Brant's *The Shyp of foyls*](https://www.otago.ac.nz/english-linguistics/tudor/BarcfoolsA.html) (The Ship of Fools), and came across two words which, for the life of me, I could not construe or make legible.
The following are the two words, as they are spelled, in excruciatingly archaic fashion, in the text:

***putueaunce***

***vtylyte***  I think I am willing to accept "utility" as the answer for this one--Thank you!

I think the second word (vtylyte) may be *vitality*, but after consulting my handy-dandy etymology dictionary, I discovered, much to my dismay, the word *vitality* is from the 1590s, although the word *vital* in its "essential to life" connotation dates back to the late 15th century.
I also thought the first word (putueaunce) might be *petulance*, but then again, the word's etymolgoy origin traces it back to at earliest the 1550s, "from French pétulance (early 16c.)" So no luck there.

Any help on cracking down these two archaic words would be lovely. I have attached scans of the two words as they appear directly from the 1509 text.

[image: putueaunce]

[image: vtylyte]

[image]
[image]

My translation:

> These fools of their minds are so blind,
> That naught they save to their own vitality,
> On wise provision they set no thing their mind.

My translation:

> I count him wise that thus doth set his brain,
> And in the summer can make such (putueaunce?)
> Whereby all his may have their sustenance.

Comment: If those are from the same text, the first one looks more like *purueaunce* than *putueaunce* to me.  (no riser, larger serif on the 'r' than on the 't' below).

Comment: It would probably be helpful to include scans of *the surrounding context* for each word.

Comment: How about _utility_  - if that fits the context?

Comment: You're mistaken about Shakespeare's use of "belongings". The full OED lists that sense as I.2 *A circumstance connected with a person or thing; something which relates to a person or thing. **Obsolete** (**archaic** in later use).* Etymonline correctly says the first recorded use of OED's sense **3** *(An item of (esp. movable) personal property, a possession, an effect. Usually with possessive adjective.) **a. In plural*** is 1817 New to me, they actually have ***I.3.b in singular*** for that same sense - flagged ***rare***, but most recent citation **2012**.

Comment: Please provide more context. I agree that the first has a *r* not a *t* and could be *purveyance;* and the second is likely to be *utility*, but isolated examples of what may be esoterically-set esoteric spellings are not going to be easy to decipher.

Comment: @AndrewLeach you beat me to it "porveaunce" was one of the *many* Anglo-Norman spellings of purveyance.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ahhh, I see. Indeed I admit of my mistaken nature. Very good to know. --I deleted that part about the "belongings", since it was mistaken, and it does not add much to the question regardless.

Comment: It should be noted that both of these seem to be influenced by the fact that prior to the 1500s, there was no distinction between _u_ and _v_; even as late as Shakespeare, it was not unusual to see them used interchangeably. I agree with the conjectures of _utility_ and _purveyance_.

Comment: My translation: *These foolish people are so lacking in mental perception or foresight and are so unaware/ That they accumulate or store nothing that will be useful to them/ They do not consider wisely providing for themselves the things they will need./ I consider someone to be wise who resolves [to act] in this [following] way/ Throughout the summer they make such a store of provisions for the future/ And from which all their family or household may have what they need.*

Answer (score 38, accepted):

These texts are from Middle English and most of the letters are composed of ***ııııııııııs***.

In Middle English, several letters such as ***u** ~ **v**, **i**, **w**, **m**, **n*** etc., were written using a sequence of a particular short downstroke of the pen/quill, called a [*minim*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minim_(palaeography)). A dotless *i* was a single minim:

[image: Minim]

- i would be one minim: ***ı***
- u, v and n would be two: ***ıı***
- m and w would be three: ***ııı***

So the word 'minim' itself would've been written:

## *ıııııııııı*

It would be ten undifferentiated minims and would've been extremely confusing.

## Purveyance

The first word in the question that looks like 'putueaunce' is ***purueaunce***, which was a variant spelling for *purveyance*. There were identical minims for *u* and *v*, so they've been used interchangeably.

[*A Concise Dictionary of Middle English (Gutenberg)*](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/10625/10625-h/dict2.html) confirms *purveaunce* and also lists some other variants including *purveyaunce*, *purveiance* and *purueance*.

Or it could be ***porveaunce*** which was the Anglo-Norman spelling for *purveyance* (as pointed out by Andrew Leach and Greybeard in the comments beneath the question).

According to *[The Language of Emare - A Middle English Romance](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3ad6/71b3ce560d02080f409bc24eae58d13872ad.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjqyPnGtsjrAhUGnxQKHS3aA7IQFjAAegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw0qKiAHRt8gV1ekrzKG8uQW&cshid=1598979587159)*:

> 458. i. PURUYANCE: ‘preparations’, **<Anglo-Norman *porveaunce*** ‘foresight,
>      provision for the future, divine Providence’.484

There are lots of quotations for *purueaunce/purveiaunce/porveaunce* in the [*Middle English Compendium*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED35322/track?counter=1&search_id=4191478) having many variants of the same spelling such as *purveiaunce, purveianse, purveaunce, perveaunce, perviaunce pourveiaunce* etc.

[*Dictionary of the Scots Language*](https://dsl.ac.uk/entry/dost/purvyance) also has some quotes using different spellings for *purveyance*, some of which are *purveance, purueianse, purueance, purvyaunce, pourveance, pourueaunce* etc.

Here's a quote from [*Sebastian Brant's The Ship of Fools (vol.2)*](https://books.google.com/books?id=8ZguFxEr-H0C&pg=PA275&dq=%22vtylyte%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=purueaunce&f=false) where *purueaunce* can be found:

> Who that maketh for hymselfe no **purueaunce**
> Of fruyt and corne in somer ...

---

## Utility

The second word is ***utility*** (as pointed out by Kate Bunting). There were identical minims for *u* and *v*. Some sources such as the [Oxford English Dictionary](https://public.oed.com/blog/early-modern-english-pronunciation-and-spelling/#spelling) claim that they were not exactly the same but were graphic variants of the same letter. The Oxford English Dictionary says that *v* was used at the beginning of a word and *u* elsewhere.

The first letter in the second word is therefore a *v*.

Furthermore, Middle English scribes adopted a practice of replacing an *i* with a *y*. Take for example the word *mine*, it was *min* in [Middle English](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/min#Middle_English), so it would've been written ***ıııııı*** and would've been indistinguishable from other combinations of relevant letters such as *win, nim, nun* etc. It was therefore replaced by a *y* (e.g. *myn* for 'mine').

[The National Archive](https://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/palaeography/where_to_start.htm) concurs that *y* was used for *i*, and *u* and *v* were interchangeable:

> **Use of y for i**, for example myne = mine
> Interchangeable i and j. Iohn = John. Maiestie = Majesty
> **Interchangeable *u* and *v*, such as euer = ever. vnto = unto**

From Harvard University Website:

> A single minim looks like:
> [image: Minim]
>
> Several minims can make up a single letter, or even a group of letters. In particular, minims are usually used for the following letters:
> One minim: "i", "j"
> Two minims: "n", "u", "v"
> Three minims: "m", "w"
>
> [[How to read Medieval texts - Harvard University Website]](https://chaucer.fas.harvard.edu/how-read-medieval-handwriting-paleography)

There are many citations for *utility/utilité/vtylyte* in the [*Middle English Compendium*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED50660/track?counter=1&search_id=4191478). Some of the spelling variants they've used for *utility* are **vtylyte**, **vtilite**, **utilite** etc.

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/utility) confirms the spelling of *utility* with an *e*:

> *Middle English **utilite***, from Anglo-French utilité, from Latin utilitat, utilitas, from utilis useful, from uti to use

The spelling ***vtylyte*** can also be found in the [*Dictionary of the Scots Language*](https://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/dost/utilite)

Here's a quote from [Sebastian Brant's The Ship of Fools (vol. 2)](https://books.google.com/books?id=8ZguFxEr-H0C&pg=PA275&dq=%22vtylyte%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22vtylyte%22&f=false) where *utility* is indeed written as *vtylyte*:

> In respect of the wele of a hole comonte
> Conioynynge thynge honest with his **vtylyte**

Answer (score 8):

P.S. I thought I would post my full translation of the page you all helped me with, as a small token of gratitude. Enjoy!

Among our fools I number him for one
/Which lies idly and in slowthfulness
/Making in the Summer no provision
/To avoid the Winter’s pain and cold hardness,
/What man will not curse and dispraise his madness
/Which at no time will for him self provide
/Of sustenance in need him self to guide.

He that begineth without advisement
/Can not provide that thing that is to come,
/Nor scantly that which must be done present
/Thus are his deeds done all without wisdom
/Of this company yet find I other some
/Which naught will save them self to find with all,
/But all out wasteth by Riot prodigal

These fools of their minds are so blind,
/That naught they save to their own utility,
/On wise provision they set no thing their mind
/But if they be driven by extreme necessity,
/As hunger, thirst, cold or other adversity
/So oft when such at vexed with most need
/They would provide but than they can not speed

A sole of property that is negligent
/For thing to come provideth nothing at all,
/But on one day seteth all his intent
/So in that space if any need do fall
/To him, he shall upon his neighbor call
/For help and secure and sore to him complain
/And ask release which he shall not obtain

When such fools have their wombs full
/They force no more nor take no farther thought
/Their vain minds to farther things is dull
/Save on that which from hand to mouth is brought
/But he is wise and of reason wanteth naught
/Which here him guideth by virtue and wisdom,
/And so provideth for the time to come

Whereby his wife, his children and offspring
/May without care other busyness or pain
/With honesty have their fode and their lineage
/Without occasion their good name to distain
/I count him wise that thus doth set his brain,
/And in the summer can make such porveaunce(purveyance)
/Whereby all his may have their sustenance

And in Winter and the hardest of the year
/But him I count much folly he and unwise
/And void of reason which maketh still good cheer,
/And by no mere will the time to come advise
/But fools follow most commonly this guise
/To sleep all Summer when the season is most clear
/And labour in the hardest season of the year

Such no thing labour nor to no work intend
/But to idleness a vice ill and damnable
/That which is gotten unwisely thus they spend,
/So that when Winter comes they are not able
/To have one lofe of bread upon their table
/Nor other thing their hunger to assuage
/An idol man is worthy such wage

In Winter he abideth a life miserable
/Which in the Summer provided hath no thing
/That to his use is need and profitable
/Who that in July while Phebus is shining
/About his hey is not busy laboring
/And other things which are for his avail
/Shall in the Winter his negligence bewail

The delightful woodcut:

[image]

Comment: ([This article on *how to read Medieval texts*](https://chaucer.fas.harvard.edu/how-read-medieval-handwriting-paleography) might be helpful. I came across this site while answering [another similar question](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/542323/365490).)